# Switch statement not displaying any results

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using android Staggered view library by Etsy and I wanted to add data on each grid. So I used switch statement in place of for loop. But no results are displaying. Is there any syntax error or should I use any other statement here?
I have commented the for loop that was originally there. Help me in being able to display strings.

```
package com.etsy.android.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SampleData {

public static final int SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT = 6;

public static ArrayList<String> generateSampleData() {
    final ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT);

    switch (SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT) {

        case 0:
            data.add("New Delhi");
            break;


        case 1:
            data.add("Mumbai");
            break;


        case 2:
            data.add("Kanpur");
            break;


        case 3:
            data.add("Hyderabad");
            break;


        case 4:
            data.add("Bangalore");
            break;


        case 5:
            data.add("Noida");
            break;


    }

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
        data.add("SAMPLE #");
    }

    */

    return data;


}
}
```

Comment: you don't have a case for `6`, value of `SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT`. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have written case 6, value of SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT and now I can see only case 6 and no other cases are visible.

Comment: Worth noting it's good practice to always include a "default" case in switch statements, and it helps identify exactly this kind of problem.  It's particularly useful for preventing regressions if anyone changes the range of possible values later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't replace a `for` loop with a `switch` statement. They are for totally different purposes. The `for` loop will run the line

```
data.add("SAMPLE #");
```

six times, but your switch statement will be executed only once and it will look for the item that matches `6`, which in your case there isn't one, so that's why nothing is displayed. If you changed the value of `SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT` to a number between `1` and `5` you'd see one item. To help you understand, your `switch` statement is exactly the same as the following `if` statement:

```
if (SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT == 0) {
        data.add("New Delhi");
} else if (SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT == 1) {
        data.add("Mumbai");
} else if (SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT == 2) {
        data.add("Kanpur");
} else if (SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT == 3) {
        data.add("Hyderabad");
} else if (SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT == 4) {
        data.add("Bangalore");
} else if (SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT == 5) {
        data.add("Noida");
}
```

but as in your case `SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT` is `6` that's why you don't see anything.

To see all your data, you need to put a `for` loop around your `switch` statement - e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_DATA_ITEM_COUNT; ++i) {
    switch (i) {

    case 0:
        data.add("New Delhi");
        break;

    case 1:
        data.add("Mumbai");
        break;

    case 2:
        data.add("Kanpur");
        break;

    case 3:
        data.add("Hyderabad");
        break;

    case 4:
        data.add("Bangalore");
        break;

    case 5:
        data.add("Noida");
        break;
    }
}
```

You could simplify things and get rid of the `switch` statement and the `for` loop altogether and just do:

```
data.add("New Delhi");
data.add("Mumbai");
data.add("Kanpur");
data.add("Hyderabad");
data.add("Bangalore");
data.add("Noida");
```

Comment: Then what should I do to be able to display all the strings?

Comment: Please see the further simplification, and also please accept the answer.